# Unable to install package libc6-compat on windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am building a docker image and it will not install libc6-compat on windows docker desktop.  This is the full error:

```
#8 [deps 2/6] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
#8 sha256:190a4effb95700083113c7ec8bd34c90330cc8b70a393b16624e72fee8f0523d
#8 0.373 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#8 0.547 48EB05913A7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
#8 0.550 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#8 0.550 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: Permission denied
#8 0.657 48EB05913A7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
#8 0.659 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: Permission denied
#8 0.659 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#8 0.661   libc6-compat (no such package):
#8 0.661     required by: world[libc6-compat]
#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache libc6-compat]: exit code: 1
------
 > [deps 2/6] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache libc6-compat]: exit code: 1
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk add git
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* .npmrc ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm set-script prepare '' && npm ci --legacy-peer-deps; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?